# Problems during old SAMBA migration re machine accounts, vampiring

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

I have an ancient but working SAMBA 3.3.4-based PDC (smbpasswd backend) on some aging hardware that I am planning to migrate to a SAMBA 4.0-based setup on a VM. Based on my reading of the various SAMBA docs, my plan was to build a SAMBA 4.0 BDC, and once it was up and running, dcpromo it and shut down the old server. Simple enough, right?

Welp...I've been able to get the BDC set up and running (mostly). I have migrated the domain SID and joined the BDC to the domain. And that's where my first problem starts.

1. I can smbclient to shares on the PDC from the BDC with no problem.
2. I can confirm the join with testjoin, and it reports the join is OK.
3. After confirming the join, I attempted a "net rpc vampire -S servername -W domainname", but after providing the appropriate credentials, I get 'Fetching (to passdb) DOMAIN database', followed immediately by 'Segmentation fault' and termination.

Looking at the samba machine-specific logs on the PDC, I see 'BAD SIG' errors during the machine credential authentication check just after I issue the vampire request. The final message in the sequence is that the machine request was rejected. The 'BAD SIG' messages are accompanied by 'SEQ 2: expected SMB signature of (blank)' and 'SEQ 2: got SMB signature of (blank)' (blank) literally meaning no data. That tells me there's something awry in the data exchange, but I'm just not sure what.

4. Checking the list of groups and users on the PDC side, I perform a "wbinfo -u" and "wbinfo -g" and both return errors - can't list user/groups. I can't even ping the winbindd process, which I verify is, in fact, running. Running 'strace' against 'wbinfo' indicates it can't talk to the winbindd pipe, but darned if I can figure out why.

So, in a nutshell, I have two problems:

1. On the BDC, I can't negotiate a secure session between my domain-joined BDC and the PDC to peform a vampire.
2. On the PDC, I can't perform a wbinfo for my groups and users.

If there are any obvious suggestions/thoughts on this, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I realize this question has not drawn a great deal of attention, I thought I would post the answer for reference.

NET RPC VAMPIRE is not intended to work in the manner I was attempting due to security differences between the two SAMBA versions.